# Project only certain fields when using MongoTemplate from Spring Data MongoDB for a find query?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I wonder how, if possible, I can execute a find query with Spring Data MongoDB using `mongoTemplate` but not return the entire document? With the "native" Java Sync driver from MongoDB I can do like this:

```
Document document = myCollection.find(eq("something", 12)).sort(descending("field")).limit(1).projection(include("field")).first();
```

so that the `document` only includes the "field" and nothing else.

How can I do the same with `mongoTemplate` since I cannot seem to find something similar to `projection` when using `mongoTemplate.findOne(..)`. Do you need to using an Aggregate pipeline to do this with `mongoTemplate`?

I'm using Spring Data MongoDB version 3.0.1.RELEASE (spring boot 2.3.3).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `include()` or `exclude()` options in the query.

ex:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.fields().include("name").exclude("id");
List<User> john = mongoTemplate.find(query, User.class);
```

Documentation Reference: [data/mongodb/core/query/Field](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Field.html)